# Why are these values not joining when I use a full join in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to join two columns from one table (ab_match) to another table (members), with one similar column between the two. However, about half of the values from the first table are not joining at all, and I can't figure out why.

When I run an anti-join between the two tables, I can see the values that are not joining.

Here is the beginning of the members tibble:

```r
`Unique ID` `Academic Background`   
   <chr>       <chr>                   
 1 1014        NA                      
 2 863         NA                      
 3 859         Political Science       
 4 855         NA                      
 5 679         NA                      
 6 141         NA                      
 7 5146        Sociology               
 8 5146        Women and Gender Studies
 9 5146        Public Policy           
10 5146        Education
```

and here is the ab_match tibble - most values in Academic Background have a counterpart in the Discipline and Topic columns that I am trying to append to the original table.

```r
`Academic Background`    Discipline               Topic                          
   <chr>                    <chr>                    <chr>                          
 1 African American Studies African Diaspora Studies Black / African American Issues
 2 Anthropology             Anthropology             NA                             
 3 Biology                  Biology                  NA                             
 4 Business                 Business                 NA                             
 5 Civic Engagement         NA                       Civic Engagement               
 6 Computer Science         Computer Science         NA                             
 7 Criminal Justice         NA                       Criminal Justice               
 8 Democracy                NA                       Democracy                      
 9 Demography               Demography               NA                             
10 Ecology                  Ecology                  NA
```

When I join using any type of join, this is the code I use:

```r
ab <- left_join(members, ab_match, by="Academic Background")
```

And this is the result I get:

```r
 `Unique ID` `Academic Background`    Discipline        Topic    
   <chr>       <chr>                    <chr>             <chr>    
 1 1014        NA                       NA                NA       
 2 863         NA                       NA                NA       
 3 859         Political Science        Political Science NA       
 4 855         NA                       NA                NA       
 5 679         NA                       NA                NA       
 6 141         NA                       NA                NA       
 7 5146        Sociology                Sociology         NA       
 8 5146        Women and Gender Studies Gender Studies    Gender   
 9 5146        Public Policy            NA                NA       
10 5146        Education                Education         Education
```

It is hard to see using the head of the code here but some values are missing. For example, I should have a matching value for Public Policy in the Discipline and Topic columns for the resulting tibble. However, other values, such as Education, are joining fine. What am I missing?

When I search for a string including "Public" using the following code:

```
str_detect(ab_match$`Academic Background`, "Public")
```

I get `TRUE` values in the output, however when I run the same code using `"Public Policy"` in place of `"Public"`, I only get `FALSE` values.

Comment: What does the subset `not_matching <- filter(ab_match, \`Academic Background\` == "Public Policy")` look like? If there are in fact rows in `ab_match` corresponding to `"Public Policy"`, can you see what happens when you join `not_matching` onto `members`?

Comment: Possibly trailing spaces? Perhaps you could share in the body of your question the result of `library(tidyverse); ab_match tibble %>% filter(`Academic Background` %>% str_detect("Public") %>% dput()`   That would let us see exactly how `ab_match tibble` is storing the Public Policy row(s).

Comment: If `head` doesn't show the issues... don't use `head`. Maybe show us `members[c(1, 2, 20:24), ]` where you specifically select rows that demonstrate the problem. Also, look at your data carefully to make sure there aren't whitespace differences. Look at `members$\`Academic Background\`` to make sure you don't have things like  `"Public Policy "` with an extra space.

Comment: This is unlikely to be caused by white space: the `tibble` print method explicitly shows double quotes around a string if it has leading or trailing spaces, e.g. `tibble::tibble(x = "y ")`.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila but we haven't  seen problem items---they weren't printed, so who knows. Less likely, but it could also be internal spaces, `"Public  Policy"` with 2 spaces vs `"Public Policy"` with 1.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. 

The subset not_matching returns just NAs, so somehow "Public Policy" data is being stored differently in one column instead of the other. 

Filtering for str_detect("Public") returns the following: 
```structure(list(`Academic Background` = character(0), Discipline = character(0), 
    Topic = character(0)), row.names = c(NA, 0L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))``` It seems as though ```"Public Policy"``` isn't being recorded at all...

Comment: That being said, `ab_match[42,]` returns ```Academic Background` Discipline    Topic        
  <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>        
1 Public Policy         Public Policy Public Policy```, so as you can see there is data in ab_match that contains the words ```"Public Policy"```.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems like the encoding was different in the two lists. I don't really know anything about working with strings so apologies for not using the right terminology. However, the join worked correct when I amended `ab_match` using the following code:

```
ab_match$`Academic Background`<-str_replace_all(ab_match$`Academic Background`, "[:space:]", " ")
```

Thank you for your help!